# Google Cloud messaging crash only on app upgrade

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-cloud-messaging

I am facing a strange issue with Google cloud messaging for iOS.
The app is crashing few seconds after calling

`[[GGLContext sharedInstance] configureWithError:&configureError];`

This happens only when Xcode installs a new app with `Google/CloudMessaging` SDK when the older version of the app downloaded from the app store is already installed.

However if I run it on a fresh install, everything works smoothly.

What could be the reason for the crash? And how to solve it?

```
// From Google GCM Sample app
// https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/ios/gcm/GcmExample/AppDelegate.m
- (void)configureGCM {
    NSLog(@"Start ConfigureGCM");
    NSError* configureError;
    [[GGLContext sharedInstance] configureWithError:&configureError];
    NSAssert(!configureError, @"Error configuring Google services: %@", configureError);
    _gcmSenderID = [[[GGLContext sharedInstance] configuration] gcmSenderID];
    NSLog(@"gcmSenderID : %@, ConfigureError: %@", _gcmSenderID, configureError);
    GCMConfig *gcmConfig = [GCMConfig defaultConfig];
    gcmConfig.receiverDelegate = self;
    [[GCMService sharedInstance] startWithConfig:gcmConfig];

    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

    _gcmRegistrationHandler = ^(NSString *registrationToken, NSError *error){
        if (registrationToken != nil) {
            NSLog(@"GCM Registration Token: %@", registrationToken);
            if(![weakSelf.user hasSyncedGCMToken]) {
                [weakSelf.user syncGCMTokenWithServer:registrationToken];
            }
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Registration to GCM failed with error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
        }
    };
    NSLog(@"End ConfigureGCM");
}
```

Here are the logs:

```
] Start ConfigureGCM
] Successfully configured [CloudMessaging].
] Failed to configure [].
] Subspecs not present, so not configured [Analytics, AdMob, SignIn, AppInvite, Maps].
] Subspecs expected to be present [CloudMessaging, Measurement].
] <GMR/INFO> App measurement v.1100000 started
] <GMR/ERROR> Exception on worker queue: data parameter is nil
] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil'
 *** First throw call stack:
(0x30cb3e83 0x3b0106c7 0x30cb3dc5 0x315f127f 0x122b73 0x1222ad 0x123bcb 0x129d9f 0x3b4f50c3 0x3b4f9e7b 0x3b4f6f93 0x3b4fa745 0x3b4fa9c5 0x3b624dff 0x3b624cc4)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Here is the screenshot of the stacktrace
[image]

[image]

## Update

This issue does not seem to be happening on iOS8 or above.
For me , crash was on iPhone 5 with iOS 7.0.4

## Update-2

For now, I am using push notification only for iOS 8+ Users. Still waiting for Google's reply [on Github](https://github.com/google/gcm/issues/113)

## Update-3

Fixed in the latest versions of GCM

Comment: Google says they fixed in in this issue: https://github.com/google/gcm/issues/124

Comment: @user102008 Thanks. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

## Update

This issue has been [fixed](https://github.com/google/gcm/issues/113) by GCM